# Trigger doctrine events without change

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a doctrine Entity which is already persisted.
There is a plugin that listens to livecycle events.

I'd like to trigger these Events without changing the entity at all.
Is this possible somehow?
I'm searching for something like that:

```
$entityManager->touch($entity)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. You can get the EventManager directly from your EntityManager and call it.

```
    $repo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(MyClass::class);
    $entity = $repo->find($parent);

    $eventArgs = new LifecycleEventArgs($entity, $this->entityManager);
    $this->entityManager
        ->getEventManager()
        ->dispatchEvent(\Doctrine\ORM\Events::postPersist, $eventArgs);
```